# Only one image available when sharing links on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I'd thought this would be rather simple to figure out, but I can't :) Any ideas why these two sites I manage differ? When I try to share links from these two sites, it works fine for eiriksandvik.no, but for atletiskutvikling.no I can only choose from 1 image on Facebook when trying to share it. Ideas?

atletiskutvikling.no/en-knallgod-ovelse-for-hoftemobilitet-hoftestabilitet-og-generell-funksjonalitet/
eiriksandvik.no/en-oppdatering-rundt-min-trening-og-mine-malsetninger/

Bad:
[image]

Good:
[image]

Comment: You might want to try asking about this on [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

use http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug ... It will show you exactly what facebook parses out of your site ... hopefully this will help you

Comment: Cool - I see that it says "Data Source "All images" extracted from all <img> nodes" for the site it works fine on and not for the failing one, but I can't say I'm able to figure out why exactly this happens...